# Find a nowhere dense closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with the following property

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $m$ be the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists a nowhere dense closed subset $F$ of $\mathbb{R}$ such that for every interval $(a,b)$ of $\mathbb{R}$, $m(F \cap (a,b)) > b-a-\epsilon$.

To be honest I'm not really sure where to start with this. The statement of the problem reminds me of Lusin's theorem, but I don't know how to apply that here. I've also thought that I might need some version of the Cantor set.

Comment: Do you know how to construct a Cantor set of positive measure?

Comment: @EricWofsey Yes - by doing something like taking out the middle fourths, right? I think I could do this problem if it was for a set interval, but I'm not sure how to provide an F that would work for any interval.

Comment: Middle fourths doesn't work: you have to make the proportions you are removing in each step get smaller and smaller fast enough.

Comment: @EricWofsey Sorry I misspoke - I meant I could for example remove the middle $(1/4)^n$-s for the $n$th step, yes?

Comment: Right, that would work.  And you can make the measure as close to the whole measure of the interval by adjusting the numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: It would be enough to get a nowhere dense closed set $F$ such that $m(\mathbb{R}\setminus F)<\epsilon$.  As a starting point, think about how to do this if you were on $[0,1]$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$: how could you construct such an $F\subset[0,1]$ with $m([0,1]\setminus F)<\epsilon$?  Then think about how you can combine such sets to work on all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Further hint for the last step:

> If you choose a closed nowhere dense subset $F_n\subset[n,n+1]$ for each $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, then $F=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}F_n$ will still be closed and nowhere dense.

Comment: Thank you for putting this as a hint - I'm practicing for an exam so it's really helpful! Okay, so I can find $F \subset [0,1]$  with $m([0,1]-F)< \epsilon$, and I understand that I could replicate this with any interval, or union together several such sets. But - say I do this for each $F_n$ as you suggested. If $m([n,n+1]-F_n) < \epsilon$, wouldn't $m(\mathbb{R} -F) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} m([n,n+1]-F_n)$, which could be much larger than $\epsilon$? How would I make the measure of the difference small enough?

Comment: Don't make $m([n,n+1]-F_n)$ equal to $\epsilon$ for each $n$--make it vary with $n$.

Comment: Okay, I see what you're getting at. Thanks for your help!